# When can we interchange functions inside the integral?

Tags: limits, functions, continuity

Let $f,g,h$ be real functions and $F$ be a probability measure. Suppose that the following holds:

$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{h(t)}{\int_x f(x,t) dF(x)} = 1,
$$
$$
\forall x: \lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{f(x,t)}{g(x,t)} = 1.
$$

Under what assumptions does it hold that

$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{h(t)}{\int_x g(x,t) dF(x)} = 1?
$$

I would like to be sure that I am not forgetting about something important when listing the assumptions for this to hold. Is it enough that $f,g,h$ are continuous?